# PANIC HELP Locked out of Postgres Databases and unable to find pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am using PgAdmin 4 to access a number of local databases created and hosted on postgresql 11. In a recent update, I set a global password for my databases, but forgot to set passwords for my user accounts (postgres and my personal account). When trying to access my databases, I repeatedly get a user authentication failure.

However, when I went looking for the pg_hba.conf file to update the permissions, I was unable to find it. I searched my entire computer including hidden folders and was only able to pg_hba.conf.sample.

I have a lot of code and data stored in these tables and it would be a serious problem to lose access to them. Any help is greatly appreciated because I don't know what else I can do!

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

After still being unable to find my pg_hba.conf file, I installed an older version of Postgresql (v9.6) with clear passwords. Going into my root PostgreSQL folder (in /Library/PostgreSQL/), I cleared permissions on the /data/ folder and manually dragged it into the older PostgreSQL version (from /Library/PostgreSQL/11 to /Library/PostgreSQL/9.6). When rebooting PgAdmin, I was able to access my old data files in the newly created 'PostgreSQL 9.6' database, though the Backup function was disabled due to conflicting version IDs. I manually exported all of the data files I needed to .csv files saved locally, and to ensure no problems in the future, I did a fresh uninstall and reinstall of PostgreSQL. After reimporting, I am happy to say I have my files restored!

Thank you all for your quick comments and suggestions!

Comment: Are you able to setup a new server in postgres, move the databases over and modify the hba_conf?  Are you sure youre on the right server looking for the file?  The file would have to exist for the instance to run so that's odd its working but not findable

Comment: Can you find postgresql.conf?  What setting does that file have for "hba_file"?